# Transpose the columns to rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a result set from a table such as the following picture:

[image]

returned by the following query:

```
SELECT [id],[siteId],[variableId],[qualifierId],[value],[valueDate],[insertDate],[insertUserID] ,[deleteDate],[deleteUserId],[dataStatus] FROM MyTable
```

I would like to transpose according this other picture:

[image]

I have tried to follow the `PIVOT` samples but I couldn't reach the result. This is my attempt (I did not include all the columns):

```
SELECT  [1281] AS q1, [1282] AS q2, [1283] AS q3, [1284] AS q4, [1285] AS q5, [1286] AS q6, [1287] AS q7, [1288] AS q8, [1289] AS q9
FROM 
(
SELECT  id, qualifierId, value, insertDate FROM BADMEntries where variableId=1000) p
PIVOT
(
    MAX(value)
    FOR qualifierId IN
    ( [1281] , [1282], [1283], [1284], [1285], [1286], [1287], [1288], [1289] )
) AS pvt
```

but did not work, because this is the result i get:
[image]

where is the error?!
thanks, diego

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: hello Mihai, i don't get an sql error but a different result as you can see from the 3rd picture in my question (just edited); the values are not in a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `id` column from your sub-query as even you are not using it in the `PIVOT` clause and in the final `SELECT` statement it is used for grouping:

```
SELECT  [1281] AS q1, [1282] AS q2, [1283] AS q3, [1284] AS q4, [1285] AS q5, [1286] AS q6, [1287] AS q7, [1288] AS q8, [1289] AS q9
FROM 
(
SELECT  qualifierId, value, insertDate FROM BADMEntries where variableId=1000) p
PIVOT
(
    MAX(value)
    FOR qualifierId IN
    ( [1281] , [1282], [1283], [1284], [1285], [1286], [1287], [1288], [1289] )
) AS pvt
```

---

Explanation:

Let's say I have the following table:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [RecordID] TINYINT
   ,[Team] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[MatchID] TINYINT
   ,[Score] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([RecordID], [Team], [MatchID], [Score])
VALUES (1, 'A', 1, 50)
      ,(2, 'A', 2, 10)
      ,(3, 'B', 1, 20)
      ,(4, 'B', 2, 40)
      ,(5, 'B', 3, 70);
```

[image]

and I want to make `PIVOT` by `[MatchID]` column and write the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @DataSource
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Score]) FOR [MatchID] IN ([1], [2], [3])
) PVT;
```

I am getting the following result (similar like you):

[image]

The issue is "caused" by the `RecordID` column as it is unique and results are group by it. So, to fix the issue I need to remove it:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT [Team]
          ,[MatchID]
          ,[Score]
    FROM @DataSource
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Score]) FOR [MatchID] IN ([1], [2], [3])
) PVT;
```

and everything works fine:

[image]